# UUPS Upgradeable Smart Contract Access Control - Ownership Transfer

Tags: solidity

I am working on a UUPS upgradeable contract that I need to transfer the ownership of to an admin.
I am using openzeppelin's AccessControl on the contract.

I read that for upgradeable contracts, the owner is not msg.sender, but it is the ProxyAdmin.

Does anyone know if this is also true for UUPS upgradeable contracts?

If yes, how do I find this proxyAdmin address?
And how do I use this proxyAdmin address to grant the admin role to another user?

Thank you so much in advance for any thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

ProxyAdmin works with TransparentUpgradeableProxy types since all that logic is handled within the proxy, whereas with UUPSUpgradeable type proxies, the logic is handled within the implementation.

So you wouldn't want to use the ProxyAdmin with the UUPS, since the functions won't line up & will instead brick your contract.

But there's probably folks better equipped on here to answer the details...

Here's some reading:
transparent vs uups: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/proxy#transparent-vs-uups
all OZ proxies: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/proxies
transparent: https://blog.openzeppelin.com/the-transparent-proxy-pattern/
proxyadmin (should be called TransparentProxyAdmin): https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/proxy#ProxyAdmin

Although OZ had created the Proxy plugin for hardhat, there isn't yet a plugin that makes it quite as simple as that for use with Foundry & the Foundry team had stated that they weren't planning on doing this at this time. There are some interesting scripts out there that can aide with this process if you're using Foundry, but they don't do the same level of checking & verifying that the OZ plugin does... yet :)